# lightline plugin doesn't load on new vim instance

Tags: vim, plugins, vim-plugins

I've trying to do this for a while and it just doesn't want to work. It installs the plugin, it shows the plugin, but upon opening a new Vim instance it just doesn't load the plugin. I think it might be something to do with macOS (I'm using Catalina) but I'm pretty sure that's not the case.

Here are the screenshots of the installed plugin:

[image]

And there is the picture of a new Vim instance with a non working plugin:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, seems like I wasn't careful enough. If using zsh shell you need to add these to both your .zshrc and .vimrc files

Add this to your .zshrc file:

```
export TERM=xterm-256color
```

And these 2 to your .vimrc file:

```
set laststatus=2
if !has('gui_running')
  set t_Co=256
endif
```

Comment: It's never a good idea to set your TERM variable unconditionally in your zshrc file.  Check your terminal emulator's settings to see if you can tell it to report its TERM as xterm-256color instead. Also, t_Co should automatically get set to 256 by Vim if your TERM variable supports it.